# Discord.js - Get Another Channel's Topic

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to basically do what the title says.

I've tried

```
let channel = message.channel.get(68352726916713XXXX)

message.channel.send(channel.topic)
```

and stuff like that, But nothing works.
Any suggestions or answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a channel in the same guild as the message was sent in, use `message.guild.channels.get`. Otherwise, use `client.channels.get`.

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.get("68352726916713XXXX");

message.channel.send(channel.topic);
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I get `Cannot read property 'topic' of undefined`

Comment: @Stuxio Make sure your channel is a TextChannel (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=topic)

Comment: @Jakye Why wouldn't it be a TextChannel? Ofc it is.

Comment: @Stuxio are you passing the channel ID as a string or a number? Snowflakes should always be strings in discord.js. You could also try to `console.log(channel);` to see what its value is.

Comment: @Genie I've tried `console.log(channel);` and still get the same error :/